# Is there any difference in how variables are referenced in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

Consider the following code:

```
name=John

echo ${name}
```

It prints "John", just as expected. Now consider this code:

```
name=John

echo $name
```

Again, this code prints "John" just as expected. Both codes work fine.

But I wonder is there any difference between the two, e.g. compatibility?

Comment: "$name" is not a definition.  You are asking if there is a difference in the way variables are referenced.

Comment: In *both* cases, the expansion should be quoted.

Comment: @chepner Can you please explain why?

Comment: @A.G. Because unquoted expansions are subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion, neither of which you usually want to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there is no difference.

In this case, there is:

```
name=John

echo ${name}Doe
echo $nameDoe
```

Read more: [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)